# Javascript Namespace ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces

Where can I accommodate ready function in the name space?

```
var yourNamespace = yourNamespace || {
    foo: function()
    {
    },
    bar: function()
    {
    }
};
...
yourNamespace.foo();
```

ready function:

```
$(function(){
...
});
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Why exactly do you need the `ready` function?

Comment: Just next to that `foo()` call? What do you mean by "*in* the namespace"?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen , I want when document is ready, inside the namespace some codes run

Comment: @Bergi i want to run this, but once namespace is defined and document gets ready:
`$(function(){
 $('button').click(foo);
});`

Comment: I'm going to migrate to namespace.

Comment: Just `$(function(){ $('button').click(namespace.foo); });` then? (If you care about `this`, use `.bind` or `$.proxy`)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I do it:

```
   var MyNamespace = (function(publicAPI) {

        var foo = 'I am a  private field';

        publicAPI.alertFoo = function() {
            alert(foo);
        };

        // DOM ready
        $(function() {        
            $('.test-link').click(function() {
                publicAPI.alertFoo();
            });
        });

        return publicAPI;

    })(MyNamespace || {});
```

To call the alertFoo method you would use MyNamespace.alertFoo(); This is a variation of the module pattern. The DOM ready section is used for binding to events.

Comment: `MyNamespace` should be the same as `myModule`…